# How to get a callback to my controller MVC4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get a postback to my controller but I can't get any response. Any ideas on how to do this?

I got a view with an iframe from Facebook that looks like this:

```
 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?

        client_id=164951196883222&

        redirect_uri=http://global.iobffp.com/SIGN-IN/&

        fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email,password"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border: none"
        allowtransparency="true"
        width="390"
        height="600">
</iframe>
```

And my controller called GetFbRegistration which is a jsonresult:

```
public JsonResult GetRegistration()
{
    return Json("something", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Now how do I get into this controller?

Comment: From where? From inside the `iframe`? Have you tried anything?

Comment: when do you want the postback? your question is unclear

Comment: Ye, when i fill the form from the iframe I want the debug so jump into my getegistration controller :)

Comment: You get into this by making a get request to http://yourdomain/YourController/GetRegistration so long as your routing is setup to allow this.

Comment: Is this your callback controller which facebook is supposed to redirect to after successful login?